# guadar imajen.png de un <div>

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, leaflet

Se ha puesto un mapa de Open Street Map y se han dibujado objetos sobre el mismo en un  hecho con leaflet, la pantalla muestra correctamente el mapa y los objetos dibujados, pero cuando quiero convertir el  en una imagen .png para descargarla en una carpeta del servidor la imagen muestra un desplazamiento de los objetos dibujados sobre el mapa, podrian ayudarme a saber porque esta sucediendo esto si simplemente quiero crear un .png de la imagen que se muestra correctamente en pantalla, es importante mencionar que cuando vuelvo a llamar el mapa, se obtiene correctamente sin el desplazamiento, solo sucede en el .png, gracias por su ayuda, les comparto el código:

```
<script>     

    function guardarMapa() {

        drawnItems.getBounds();
        var todosJSON = [];
          drawnItems.eachLayer(function(layer) {
            var type1 = layer.options.type;
            var coordinates = layer.toGeoJSON().geometry.coordinates;
            var area = L.GeometryUtil.geodesicArea(layer._defaultShape());
            var areaLegible = L.GeometryUtil.readableArea(area, true);
            var objetoJSON = {
              "layerType": type1,
              "coordinates": coordinates
            };
            todosJSON.push(objetoJSON);
          });
           var zoom = map.getZoom(); 
           var center = map.getCenter()   
           var zoomMapaJSON = {
            "zoom": zoom,
            "centro": center
          };
          todosJSON.push(zoomMapaJSON);
          var todosJSONString = JSON.stringify(todosJSON);

          html2canvas(document.getElementById('map'), {
          useCORS: true
              
            }).then(canvas => {document.body.appendChild(canvas)
                var imagenBase64 = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open("POST", "guardar_mapa.php", true);
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");              
                var data =                
                  "&clado=" + encodeURIComponent("<?php echo $foldo; ?>") +
                  "&imagen=" + encodeURIComponent(imagenBase64);
                xhr.send(data);
            });
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {var response = xhr.responseText;}};
    }   
 </script>
```

Comment: El contenedor tiene un tamaño fijo???

Comment: Puede haber diferencias en las coordenadas o en el sistema de coordenadas utilizado entre Leaflet y html2canvas

Comment: si has llegado a este punto asumo que tendras la capacidad de hacer el debug de esos dos argumentos.

Comment: ahora la pregunta no tiene nada que ver con php evitar usar etiquetas que no tienen nada que ver con el codigo y escenario.

Comment: Estimado ArcanisGK507, agradezco mucho tus respuestas y atencios, te respondo cada una para ver si puedes ayudarme en saber en que me estoy equivocando. 1. si tiene un tamaño fijo: <style>
      #map {
        height: 350px;
        width: 90%;
      }
    
    2. no se como los sistemas de coordenadas se puedan ajustar en html2canvas,si me quedan claros en leaflet, pero no se como manejarlos en html2canvas
    3. disculpa mi ignorancia pero no comprendo el concepto de debug de los argumentos, solo se me ocurre que estoy usando 90% en el tamaño, pero investigare respecto al debug

Comment: 4. ya que uso un archivo destino en .php (guardar_mapa.php) y sentencias ajax por eso etiquete php, ya que yo pense que el problema podia estar en relacion con el POST y que por eso se desplazaba, sin embargo tienes razon el contexto es javascript, gracias por la recomendacion
    
    Realmente agradezco mucho tus respuestas y espero me puedas ayudar en poder entender un poco mas esta problematica, gracias por todo.

Comment: el post no tiene nada que ver el ajax y el php, enviaran y recibiran lo capturado... no hay manera que el php o el ajax mueva los dibujos etc ... asique descarta esa parte... si el armado del png ocurre en el javascript es hay que tienes que hacer el debug, el debug son metodos de visualizacion de datos y comparacion de comportamientos por el cual validas que el codigo esta haciendo paso a paso lo esperado ...

Comment: hay es donde entra entonces el tema de las coordinadas, son las misma para ambos sitemas?; cuando capturas algo en los dos sistemas por separado existe correspondencia en las coordenadas?, estas seguro de que estas capturando la informacion correcta? estas son cosas que debes comprobar/evaluar antes de ...